# Determining which values a coefficient can take

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following system and matrix:

$-x_1 + 3x_2-2x_3 = 7\\4x_1 + 2x_2-6x_3 = 14\\4x_1 + 5x_2+\textit{a}x_3 = 23\\$

$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 & -2\\4 & 2 & -6\\4 & 5 & \textit{a} \end{pmatrix}$

The question is to determine for all values of $\textit{a}$ how many solutions the system has: none, exactly one, infinitely many.

I have two ways of solving this, the first one by finding the determinant:

$((-1)\cdot 2 \cdot \textit{a}) + (3\cdot (-6) \cdot 4) + ((-2)\cdot 4\cdot5) - (4\cdot 2\cdot(-2))-(5\cdot (-6)\cdot (-1))-(\textit{a}\cdot 4\cdot 3)=-14\textit{a}-126=\textit{a}-9$

From this, I would say there are infinitely many solutions, namely $(-\infty, 9)\cup(9, \infty)$.

But if this is the case, how can I determine for all values of $\textit{a}$?

The second one is by doing elimination. I will end up with this matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 & -2&|&7\\0 & 1 & -1&|&3\\0 & 0 &\textit{a}+9&|& 0 \end{pmatrix}$

But then I get stuck, because I don't know how to continue from this. Should I do the following?:

$\textit{a}+9 = 0$, so $\textit{a} = -9$ and thus getting the following matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 & -2&|&7\\0 & 1 & -1&|&3\\0 & 0 &-9&|& 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: "Solutions"? Solutions... **to what** ?

Comment: @DonAntonio solutions for all the values of $\textit{a}$. At least, that is what is says here in my book. "Determine for all values of $\textit{a}$ how many solutions the system has". I'm not a native English speaker, and the book isn't in English as well. That's as good as I can translate it.

Comment: Once again: solution **for what** , @Garth ? What system is that book talking about? A matrix by itself has no solutions...

Comment: @DonAntonio - Made an edit to my post. There should now be a system.

Comment: Now you've written a logical question, @Garth...finally!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain value(s) of $a$ will give you a system of equations (represented by the augmented coefficient matrix) with one unique solution, other values will give you a system of equations for which there are infinitely many xolutions, and you also need to find whether any values $a$ reveal an unsolvable (inconsistent) system of equations, for which there are no solutions. No value of $a$ will give you all three, concurrently.

In the first method, if done correctly, you find that the determinant is zero when $a = -9$: $$-14\textit{a}-126=-14({\bf a+9) = 0 \iff a = - 9}$$

In the last case, if $a = - 9$, then $a + 9 = 0$, and the bottom row zero's out:

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 & -2&|&7\\0 & 1 & -1&|&3\\0 & 0 &\textit{a}+9&|& 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ giving you the knowledge that there are infinitely many solutions when $a = -9$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 & -2&|&7\\0 & 1 & -1&|&3\\0 & 0 &{-9}+9&|& 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 & -2&|&7\\0 & 1 & -1&|&3\\0 & 0 & 0&|& 0 \end{pmatrix}$$So you've shown that when $a$ takes on the value of $-9$, the system of equations corresponding to the augmented coefficient matrix has infinitely many solutions. You can assign any parameter to the third variable of the system, and the other two variables will be functions of the third variable.

Now you need to determine:

- Which values of $a$ give you only one solution?
- Are there any values of $a$ for which the system of equations corresponding to the augmented coefficient matrix has NO solutions?

Comment: I can't understand: solution... **to what** ?

Comment: @DonAntonio It seems pretty clear that the matrix represents a system of equations: it's an augmented coefficient matrix representing that system.

Comment: *what* system? Until 3 minutes ago when the OP finally edited his answer and wrote the actual system there was no system there...

Comment: @DonAntonio I see your confusion. I guess I "knew" that's what was beign asked, since I was focusing on the row-reduced augmented coefficient matrices at the end. Unfortunately, many students post those without the corresponding explicit equations written. I just noticed that the first matrix is not "augmented." So I can see where there'd be confusion (and frustration!)

Comment: Indeed so, @amWhy . The truth is that here I do exactly what I'd do in university (and have *actually* done) if my students wrote so sloppy questions/explanations/arguments.... with the difference that I don't grade here. :) +1

Comment: I've no many hopes that'll progress, @amWhy : there still are several suggestions to improve this site that haven't gone anywhere.

Comment: @amWhy - I would say that are no values of $\textit{a}$ for which the system of equations has no solutions, because for that the bottom row should be in the format $\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0& 0 & | &7\end{pmatrix}$, which it isn't. Since we found a value that produces infinitely many solutions, we have no NO solutions, then there's just one left for all the other values: only one solution for all the values $\neq -9$.

Comment: @Garth Exactly! You've got it!

Comment: @amWhy: This + makes 88 to be 98. ;-)